# Get index after push

Tags: mongodb, push

How do I get new index after use `$push` modifier to push a new value into an array?

For example, I have an array in a doc,

```
{ ...
    'myarray': [1, 2, 3]
 ....
}
```

After push say number 10 in `myarray`, wish to get index number 3.

I am thinking use `count` method, but think it wouldn't be atomic.

Comment: Are all the elements of your arrays unique or can there be duplicates?

Comment: Can be either unique or duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would not be atomic. The best way to do something like this is to use findAndModify:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command

Here's an example that would atomically apply the $push update and return the resulting document. Note that the findAndModify call returns the "new" document with the push applied. This is atomic.

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.1.0
connecting to: test
> db.z.save({"a":[], "name": "list1"})
> db.runCommand({ "findAndModify": "z", "query": { "name": "list1" }, "update": { "$push": { "a": 64 } }, "new": true })
{
        "lastErrorObject" : {
                "updatedExisting" : true,
                "n" : 1,
                "connectionId" : 65,
                "err" : null,
                "ok" : 1
        },
        "value" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("4ee27202c469f4b2d3c6cbf9"),
                "a" : [ 
                        64
                ],
                "name" : "list1"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
> db.z.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ee27202c469f4b2d3c6cbf9"), "a" : [ 64 ], "name" : "list1" }
```

You would then compute the index in client code. Note that subsequent operations MAY render this index invalid (i.e., a subsequent remove, $set, or $pull) -- handling this case is dependent on your application.